# Display the_content on click jquery

Tags: loop, get-posts

I'm trying to display the_content of a post on click.

the problem I'm having is that it display always display the same content.

I mean by on click on read for post A, it display the_content of post A, but also the one of post B, post C, etc.

Here was my original code:

```
 <ul class="top-stories">  <?php query_posts('showposts=2&post_type=post'); ?> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                             <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                    <div class="top-story-image"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?>
                                    </div><!--top-story-image-->

                                         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                </a>
                                         <a class="go" href="javascript:void(0)">read more</a>
                                         <div class="pop" style="display:none"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            </li>

                               <?php endwhile; else : ?><p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p> <?php endif; ?>

                        </ul>
```

and my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.go').click(function() {
   $('.pop').fadeIn('500');
    });
```

To solve this, Im' trying to assign a pos-ID class and using a variable, 
However my jquery skills are limited unfortunately.

So far, I tried this:

```
<ul class="top-stories">  <?php query_posts('showposts=2&post_type=post'); ?> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                             <li>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                                    <div class="top-story-image"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb'); ?>
                                    </div><!--top-story-image-->

                                         <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                </a>
                                          <a id="go_<?php echo($post->ID); ?>" href="javascript:void(0)">read more</a>
                                         <div class="pop_<?php echo($post->ID); ?>" style="display:none"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                            </li>

                               <?php endwhile; else : ?><p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p> <?php endif; ?>

                        </ul>
```

and using in jquery:

```
   $('a#go_' + post_id).html();).click(function() {
  var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (post_id != '') {
      var content = $('.pop_' + post_id).html();
      $('.pop').html(content).show();
      });
```

but it doesn't work out ..

Any highlite - or if 'm on the good way would be amazing;

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following javascript  you need to add class to a tag for read more

`<a class='readmode'>Read More</a>`

```
$('.readmode').click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('.pop').slideToggle();
     return false;
});
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/fvcvyc1e/4/

Comment: HI, Thank you.

IT doesn't seem to work . . . i've try to add the class you put by keeping the id and the href, didn't work. I also try just putting the class you said without the previous id and Href and dint change anything . . . .

Do you have any other suggestions by any chance :( ?

Comment: Can you please give me page link so i will check out

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunalty I can't provide any link I'm afraid :( :( DO you have nay other suggestion by any chance :(

Comment: Can you please update your html css and javascript for the particulate block on http://jsfiddle.net/fvcvyc1e/4/ and let me know i will check out

Comment: Let me know if you are updating code over the jsfiddle or not

Comment: Hi, THank you for your time<

I have add the html here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvcvyc1e/5/

let me know what is wrong with it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24990/discussion-between-mitul-and-user3439889).

Comment: Hi here is the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/fvcvyc1e/12/ please check out